# Binder Jupyter notebook missing some dependencies from environment.yml

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter notebook that I've put on Binder.  In general it works great, and I specify my dependencies in binder/environment.yml.  However, one of my dependencies -- `xlwt` -- is being ignored even though it is in my environment file.

All of my other dependencies are correctly extracted from environment.yml, so I'm wondering what the difference is.  `xlwt` isn't called directly in the notebook, but it is used by pandas to export to Excel.

Looking at the Build logs, I see that that module is never installed into the environment.  Is there a way to *force* it?  Maybe I should be using a Dockerfile instead?

https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#preparing-a-repository-for-binder

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a Dockerfile is only needed for very complex environments.
I suspect you need to have pip install `xlwt` and not rely on the anaconda distribution for that. Sometimes it is hard to know which to use for things that seem to be able to be handled by either and you have to try some combinations. This example [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/fiona-feedstock/issues/76#issuecomment-394801589) shows how to combine used pip to install `xlwt` in an `environment.yml` file.